# How many 10 digit numbers are there so the sum of the digits is $2$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

How many 10 digit numbers are there so the sum of the digits is $2$?

$abcdefghij$ is the 10 digit number. By default, $a=1$ is a **must**.

$= 1bcdefghij$

Now we need: $bcdefghij = 1$

How can I solve this combinatorically? Not by checking and substitution?

Comment: Why must $a=1$? What's wrong with $2000000000$?

Comment: "checking and substitution" opens quite often a fruitful route to "combinatorics".

Answer (score 6):

if $a=1$, for the rest $9$ places, $1$ can be taken anywhere, and also the rest $8$ places must be $0$ or the sum would exceed $2$.

Also if $a=2$, then the rest $9$ places must be $0$, or sum would exceed $2$.

Hence there are $9+1=10$ such numbers.

Comment: I assume you meant that the rest of the $9$ places would be $0$ if $a = 2$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes ofcourse, thank you :)